# constexpr and CRTP: compiler disagreement

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

When expression templates are implemented using CRTP, the class at the top of the expression hierarchy uses base-to-derived downcasting in order to implement some of its operations. According to clang-3.5 (`-std=c++1y`), this downcast should be illegal in `constexpr` functions:

```
test.cpp:42:16: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
        static_assert(e() == 0, "");
                      ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:26: note: cannot cast object of dynamic type 'const base<derived>' to type 'const derived'
        const noexcept { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)(); }
```

GCC happily [compiles the code.](http://ideone.com/VZQ8Mz) So who is right? If Clang is right, which C++14 restriction on `constexpr` functions makes this downcasting illegal?

Here's the MWE:

```
template <class Derived>
class base
{
public:
    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)(); }
};

class derived : public base<derived>
{
public:
    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return 0; }
};

template <class A, class B>
class expr : public base<expr<A, B>>
{
    const A m_a;
    const B m_b;
public:
    constexpr explicit expr(const A a, const B b)
    noexcept : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}

    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return m_a() + m_b(); }
};

template <class D1, class D2>
constexpr auto foo(const base<D1>& d1, const base<D2>& d2)
noexcept { return expr<base<D1>, base<D2>>{d1, d2}; }

int main()
{
    constexpr auto d = derived{};
    constexpr auto e = foo(d, d);
    static_assert(e() == 0, "");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the `operator()` in `base` to do a valid `static_cast`, the most-derived object that `this` points to must be of type `Derived` (or a subclass thereof). However, the members of `e` are of type `base<derived>`, not `derived` itself. In the line

```
const noexcept { return m_a() + m_b(); }
```

`m_a` is of type `base<derived>`, and `base<derived>::operator()` is called - **with a most-derived object of type `base<derived>`**.
Thus the cast tries to cast `*this` to a reference to object type that it doesn't actually refer to; That operation would have undefined behavior as [expr.static.cast]/2 describes:

> An lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`,” where B is a class type, can be cast to
>   type “reference to *cv2* `D`,” where `D` is a class
>          derived (Clause 10) from `B` [..]. **If the object of type “*cv1* B” is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the result refers
>   to the enclosing object of type `D`**. **Otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

And subsequently, [expr.const]/2 applies:

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a core constant expression unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> (2.5) — an operation that would have undefined behavior

Instead, rewrite `foo` as follows:

```
template <class D1, class D2>
constexpr auto foo(const D1& d1, const D2& d2)
noexcept { return expr<D1, D2>{d1, d2}; }
```

And the code [**works fine**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55ffe9e53ef6743d).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that Clang is right in this case.  The type of `e` is `const expr<base<derived>, base<derived>>`, so `m_a` and `m_b` have type `base<derived>`, rather than `derived`.  In other words, you have [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/502399) `d` when copying it into `m_a` and `m_b`.

Comment: I think the asker is looking for standard references.

Comment: @Columbo I will attempt to find some.  But as a general rule most (all?) things that are undefined behaviour at runtime are errors in `constexpr` evaluations.

Comment: I thought the code is fine, let me have a closer look

Comment: @Columbo The dynamic type of `e.m_a` and `e.m_b` is `base<derived>`, not `derived`.  If you [use `dynamic_cast` instead](http://ideone.com/QiheGH), a `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown.

Comment: Indeed, you're correct. I'll write an own answer with standard quotes if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent rework of your original code.  UB is removed, and it extends nicely:

```
namespace library{
  template <class Derived>
  class base
  {
  public:
    constexpr Derived const& self() const noexcept { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this); }

    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return self()(); }
  };

  template <class A, class B>
  class expr : public base<expr<A, B>>
  {
    const A m_a;
    const B m_b;
  public:
    constexpr explicit expr(const A a, const B b)
    noexcept : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}

    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return m_a() + m_b(); }
  };

  template <class D1, class D2>
  constexpr auto foo(const base<D1>& d1, const base<D2>& d2)
  noexcept { return expr<D1, D2>{d1.self(), d2.self()}; }
}

namespace client {
  class derived : public library::base<derived> {
  public:
    constexpr auto operator()()
    const noexcept { return 0; }
  };
}


int main()
{
  constexpr auto d = client::derived{};
  constexpr auto e = foo(d, d);
  static_assert(e() == 0, "");
}
```

Basically every `base<X>` **must** be a `X`.  So when you store it, you store it as an `X`, not a `base<X>`.  We can access the `X` via `base<X>::self()` in a `constexpr` fashion.

By doing it this way, we can put the machinery into `namespace library`.  `foo` can be found via ADL, and if you (for example) start adding operators to your expression-template like code, you won't have to manually import them for your `main` to work.

Your `derived` is a class created by client code for your library, so goes in another namespace.  It overrides `()` as it pleases, and it "just works".

A less contrived example would replace `foo` with `operator+`, and the advantages of this style become apparent.  `main` becomes `constexpr auto e = d+d;` without having to `using library::operator+`.

The changes made are adding a `self()` method to `base` to access `Derived`, using it to remove a `static_cast`s in `()`, and having `foo` return an `expr<D1, D2>` instead of a `expr<base<D1>, base<D2>>`.

Comment: Why is `self` necessary?

Comment: @columbo saves typing of the same cast again and again?  We want derived from the CRTP base quite often.

Comment: @columbo or are you asking why not just make `foo` take `D1` and `D2` directly?  Easier than the sfinae test that `base<D1>` is a base of `D1` is to just take `base<D1>` and call `self()` to get back to `D1`.  And we get ADL.

Comment: You make expr<> take the self bit, not foo. Why?  (I cannot check the standard right now, but I'm fairly sure that ADL only works for unqualified-ids)

Comment: @columbo Suppose `foo` and `base` are defined in `namespace A`, as they should be.  Now `derived` may be defined in `namespace B`.  `derived d; foo(d,d)` will find `base<derived>` but not `derived`.  This is mildly useful for free functions, but rather crucial for operators, and as the OP appears to be writing expression template code, operators **will** show up.  The alternative is forcing users to manually import every symbol and call, which sucks. [here is a use of the technique](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec4013aff8f8214)

Comment: Nevermind, I solely missed the fact that "your" `foo` still takes the base class reference :) *+1*